# Authorization Policies Laravel 5.3, return only 'This action is unauthorized'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm learning about the policies in Laravel 5.3 and I'm having a problem, it always returns 'This action is unauthorized'. what am I doing wrong? Here are the codes:

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('list');

        $users = User::all();
        return $users;
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\User' => 'App\Policies\UserPolicy',
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

**UserPolicy.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function list(User $user)
    {
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try moving $users statement above authorize() and then passing to authorize() as second argument?

Comment: yes, same problem. I added an echo in the policy list method to test, and it did not display anything, it looks like it's not calling the method.

Comment: Does printing $user give anything? As a test, remove Typehint User from list() and then try.

Comment: Nothing, I removed the parameter from the list () method there from the policy, I put an echo and a die. It continues to display the page of 'This action is unauthorized. ty for help!

Comment: FYI-- my IDE gives error at function name since "list" is a php function. Try renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a second argument set to the model class when calling the `authorize` method, otherwise how will laravel know which `list` method/policy to check for authorization? Other models could also have a `list` method/policy, hence the need for a second argument.

```
$this->authorize('list', User::class);
```